# Get the Caption of associated Label for a Form Control - Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

As the title suggests, I'm trying to get the caption of the associated label for form controls
eg:

```
Dim ctl As Control
Dim errMess As String
errMess = ""
For Each ctl In frm
    With ctl
            If (ctl.Tag = "*") Then
        errMess = errMess & ctl.Caption & vbNewLine        
            End If
        End If
   End With
Next ctl
```

Obviously "ctl.Caption" doesn't work, I'm just not sure how to reference this.

Any help appreciated.

Cheers

Noel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the answer is to use ctl.Controls.Item(0).Caption

```
Dim ctl As Control
Dim errMess As String
errMess = ""
For Each ctl In frm
    With ctl
            If (ctl.Tag = "*") Then
        errMess = errMess & ctl.Controls.Item(0).Caption & vbNewLine        
            End If
        End If
   End With
Next ctl
```

Comment: This will work only if the label is attached to the control. Also note that some control types, like an Option Group, have more than one control, and theoretically, .Controls(0) might be something other than the option group's label. And, of course, you can use ctl.Controls(0).Caption with no need for the Item().

Comment: Thanks for the advice David, this is something that I would have overlooked completely.